# How do I efficiently count distinct fields in a collection?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am currently doing this:

```
val count = sightings.map(_.shape).distinct.length
```

However, `map` creates an intermediary collection, which in my case is a Vector thousands of times larger than what `distinct` produces.

How do I bypass this intermediate step and get the set of distinct shapes? Or, even better, the count of distinct shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an iterator to not create the intermediate collection and then accrue the shapes in a `Set` to get the distinct ones:

```
val count = sightings.iterator.map(_.shape).toSet.size
```

Alternatively, you can use `collection.breakOut` to accrue the items in a `Set` without creating the intermediate collection (another answer suggested using `breakOut`, but in a different way):

```
val distinctShapes: Set[Shape] = sightings.map(_.shape)(collection.breakOut)
val count = distinctShapes.size
```

Comment: I am getting "value distinct is not a member of Iterator[String]"

Comment: Makes sense. I'll edit the answer to fix my mistake. The solution would be to turn the iterator into a `Set` and then getting the size of that.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to remove the duplicates as you go, then count the results.

```
sightings.foldLeft(Set[Shape]()){case (ss,sight) => ss + sight.shape}.size
```

The intermediate `Set` of shapes is only as big as all the distinct shapes encountered so far.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the other answers, there is an exact solution for your problem.

`Breakout`is the key you are looking for.

Example usage:

```
 import scala.collection.breakOut
 val count = sightings.map(_.shape)(breakOut).distinct.length
```

Here, using `breakOut` prevents creating intermediate collections.

You can read [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/breakout.html) for more information.

Comment: `breakOut` allows you to not create an intermediate collection when you need to go from one collection to the other (going from a collection of pairs to a map without having an intermediate collection is the most popular example). In this case what you need is a lazy operation between the `map` and the `distinct`. However, your example can be leveraged if we use a `Set`, like this: `val distinctShapes: Set[Shape] = sightings.map(_.shape)(collection.breakOut); val count = distinctShapes.size`

Comment: I am afraid I couldn't understand your point. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `breakOut` serves as a way to go change the resulting collection _while_ performing a `map` (among several operations). It will not allow you to skip the creation of an intermediate collection in your example because the `distinct` occurs _after_ you `map`ped. But if you use a `Set` as the target collection, picking distinct items will be performed while the `Set` is built, saving the construction of the intermediate collection.

Comment: I edited my answer to include the example of how to use `breakOut` to skip the creation of an intermediate collection.

Comment: Yes, now I see. In my answer, using the `breakout` only prevents the creating intermediate collection of `map` function, which is still an answer for the question. But with your correction, it becomes better.